# Putting my node.js app online

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hosting, launch

So, the last two months I've been developing a Node.js app for a course in school, and on Monday it needs to be online so that my teachers can have a look at it.

How can I do this? I could really need some help here.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm using Mongodb for my database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I host a Node.js app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an always-on internet connection (e.g. DSL/cable) and are behind a router? Then you can NAT the ports your node.js app is listening on to your computer, make sure to check windows firewall as well.

Now your app is online on your private computer!

Comment: Ah, this could work, but doesn't it need me to have a static ip?

Comment: nope, you can use your plain old dynamic ip or use dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 4):

I've found [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is easy and free to host a node.js app with MongoDB.

Comment: Is it easy to set up? I have a lot of files (+2000) including a bunch of installed modules.

Comment: Yes, you add the files with git, and the modules you declare in a file called "procfile". The details are [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs).

Comment: @holyredbeard, just follow [the guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs).

Comment: you have to provide your cc details for mongoDB

Answer (score 3):

openshift gives better free package. Deployment is easy as on heroku. I'm using it now for developing one app in mean.js style and I'm very happy with it.